# Where can I put global ajax error handling in Ember?

Tags: ajax, ember-data, ember-cli

In my application's adapter, I'm returning error codes based on ajax errors.  I'm handling these in the application route's error method.  This works great if I access a route via link-to.  But if I refresh a route or just type the URL in, my application's error handler isn't called.  Is there a place where I can put this error handling that will be guaranteed to run every time?  I really don't want to implement the same "if 401, show login" code in every single route.

routes/application.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function(reason) {
        if (reason === 401) {
          alert('401');
            this.send('showLogin');
        }
    },
```

adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    'namespace': '',
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);
    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 401) {
        return 401;
    }
    return error;
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

The above code nearly worked for me.  The main issue I hit was this.send('showLogin') wasn't being caught when refreshing or hitting the URL.  Changing this to a transitionTo works great:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  actions: {
    error: function(reason) {
      if (reason === 401) {
        this.transitionTo('login');
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: I also have this problem and couldn't find a global solution. Did you ever get it resolved? I posted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926638/ember-handling-401s-revisited-in-2015

Comment: Yeah, I finally got it working.  See the above edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an application adapter, and then extend every adapter from this, and use isInvalid function.

```
//app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

    isInvalid(status, headers, payload){ 
        if (status===401) {}
    },

});

//app/adapters/anotherAdapter.js

import AppAdapter from 'yourapp/adapters/application';

export default AppAdapter.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) promises, then

```
Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {
    // ...
});
```

Or if you're using plain jQuery xhr

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(evt, jqXHR) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This definitely works, but I was hoping to handle it globally.  I can catch them all in the adapter and return an error, but the application route doesn't always catch it like I expect.