# Ember Handling 401s Revisited in 2015

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, error-handling, ember-data

I can find a ton of old questions asking/answering how to handle 401s from the Rails backend in Ember/Ember Data. Many, if not all, seem to be outdated at this point. I have tried everything I could find. ([Ember-Data handling 401’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981563/ember-data-handling-401-s))

But no matter what I do I just keep getting 401 errors in the console while the 401s are never caught in my code. All I want to do is add a redirect to '/' if a 401 is ever encountered in any place/model/anything. I don't need any checking for authentication or anything else.

I have tried adding this to the Application Route actions as well as to to the Router itself.

```
error: function (error, transition) {
  console.log("err: " + error.status);
  if (error && error.status === 401) {
    return this.transitionToRoute('/');
  }
}
```

I've also tried several variations of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063009/1850353.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);
    console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status);
    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 401) {
      #handle the 401 error
    }
    return error;
  }
});
```

I'm obviously a noob so maybe I'm missing something simple here. None of my console.log's are getting triggered unless it's for a new error I've introduced trying to get this to work. Is there a current, 'best practice' style way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controllers and Routes

With logic that is executed in a controller or route, you generally have an `error` action attached to the route. If an action is triggered on a controller and the controller doesn't handle that action (e.g. there is no `error` action in the controllers `actions` hash) then it is automatically passed to the route to get a chance to handle - if the current route doesn't handle the action either it bubbles to parent routes until it hits the `ApplicationRoute`.

The way I handle it is have an `AuthenticatedRoute` that any route that needs to handle a 401 extends from. Also, in the example you've linked to - it has `events` whereas it's now `actions`.

Something like this should work for you:

```
    App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

        actions: {
        error: function(error) {
            if (!error || error.status !== 401) {
                // returning true bubbles the error to parent routes
                return true; 
            }

                // put your logic here
                console.log('this is a 401 error.');
            }
        }

    });

    App.IndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
        //logic
    });

    App.FooRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
        //logic
    });

    App.BarRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
        //logic
    });
```

## Components

Ember is moving more and more towards components - the thing with logic executed in components is that it's completely isolated from everything else. Generally the only things available to you in your components are the things you pass into them.

This means that if you're executing some logic in a component none of the logic above - the logic that exists on the routes to handle errors - is used unless you explicitly use it yourself.

If your making calls like `store.find('person', 1)` or `person.save()` in a component you need to handle the errors explicitly using the `.catch()` function or passing a second function to the `.then()`. For example the following two statements would do the same thing:

```
    store.find('person', 1).then(function(person) {
        console.log('found person 1:', person);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('error finding person 1:', err);
    });

    store.find('person', 1).then(function(person) {
        console.log('found person 1:', person);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error finding person 1:', err);
    });
```

And so would these two statements:

```
    person.save().then(function() {
        console.log('successfully saved person');
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('error saving person:', err);
    });

    person.save().then(function() {
        console.log('successfully saved person');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error saving person:', err);
    });
```

#### Reusing the Route Error Logic in Components

If you want to pass the error handling in your components onto your routes to deal with the best way to do that is have the component fire an action and have the calling template/view/controller handle it.

`app/components/my-component.js`

```javascript
    Ember.Component.extend({
        'on-error': null,
        model: null,
        actions: {
            save: function() {
                var component = this;
                var model = this.get('model');

                mode.save().then(function() {
                    console.log('saved');
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    component.sendAction('on-error', err);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

`app/templates/components/my-component.hbs`

```html
    <button {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
```

`app/templates/index.hbs`

```html
    <!-- 
        Passing the 'error' action to the components 'on-error' property links the 'on-error' 
        action on the component with the 'error' action on the controller - if the controller 
        doesn't handle it, it's bubbled up to the route to handle
    -->

    {{my-component model=model on-error='error'}}
```

Comment: Since I want to do this everywhere, it seems like I should be able to just add the error action to the application route `[ember-root]/app/routes/application.js`. Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: Usually you want it everywhere except one route.. This one route is the one you redirect to.. You usually don't want to have the redirect logic on that route - it would redirect back to itself.. Depending on the app you could get stuck in a never ending loop.

Comment: I've tried all kinds of variations of this now both in the application route and with a separate route. I'm still just getting the 401 errors in the console(`PUT http://localhost:3000/api/posts/46 401 (Unauthorized)`) but the code doesn't catch it.

Comment: Ah, we have our login page in Rails but the rest of the app in Ember. So I'm trying to redirect to that one rails page.

Comment: The PUT request that gets the 401 - where is that executed? What triggers the PUT request?

Comment: An Ember component that is trying to save a change to the model. We check for whether the model in Ember isDirty and save to the Rails backend automatically. Right now if I sign out of the app in one tab, any other remaining tabs will not be able to reach the Rails backend(as desired) but they just show the 401 in the console. I'm trying to get them to just redirect to the login which is a rails page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the situation you're having. Components are isolated so any of the error handling logic that exists on the routes/controllers is not used in your components.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks so much for your updated answer. We have about 10+ components where this is applicable. I would have thought Ember could just sort of listen for 401s globally.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the two other answers here are good and will work fine, but have a few undesirable caveats IMHO.

I would strongly recommend implementing an `Ember.onerror` hook. Any unhandled promise rejections will end up at that hook. You can implement it with an initializer if you're using Ember-CLI.

```
// app/initializers/on-error.js
export default {
  name: 'on-error',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    Ember.onerror = function(error) {
      if(error && error.status === 401) {
        // Ember 2.1 adds a public lookup function. Older versions
        // need to use the container.
        var router = app.lookup ? app.lookup('router:main') :
                     app.__container__.lookup('router:main');
        // Even future versions of ember are likely to have an 
        // accessible router service to do this work.
        router.transitionTo('sign-in');
      }

      if(error && error.stack) {
        // Uncaught exception - Log stacktrace to server
      }
    };
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, this will handle all uncaught promise rejections. So this still provides you with a good bit of flexibility to handle promises locally in a component. For example:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    saveChanges: function() {
      this.get('model').save().then(null, (reason) => {
        if(/* reason is validation error */) {
          this.set('validationError', reason.errorMsg);
        } else {
          throw reason;
        }
      })
    }
  }
 });
```

Take notice that in the promise rejection handler above if we couldn't handle the error, we rethrow it. This is very important. Rethrowing the error will give any additional chained promise handlers the chance to deal with it. And ultimately it will make it's way up to `Ember.onerror` if left unhandled.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ember 1.13.8 & Ember Data 1.13.9, my authenticated routes use:

```
actions: {
  error: function(reason, transition) {
    if (reason.errors[0].status === '401') {
      this.transitionTo('sign-in');
    }
  }
}
```